# Read from txt file and input to an array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have my txt file

```
4  
110  
220  
112  
335
```

4 is the number of lines and 4*3 the number of int. I have to read "4" then read the remaining and input them into an array

This is what I have

```
void main(){ 
    int a,n;    
    int i=0,j=0,k[30]; //
    int *N;

    FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");  
    if(fscanf(fp, "%d", &a) != 1) { //
       // something's wrong 
    }

    n=3*a; //3*a numbers in the file
    N = malloc(3 * a * sizeof(int)); 
    for(i = 0; i <n;++i) {
       int result=fscanf(fp, "%d", &N[i] );  
    }   
    fclose(fp);  
    for(j=0;j<3*a;j++){  
       k[j]=N[j]; 
    }

    printf("%d",k[0]);
 }
```

When I print `k[0]` it was supposed to print "1" but instead the whole line "110" is printed

Is there any other way to do this???

Comment: You're trying to read four *numbers* as twelve *digits*. Your code will read 4 *int* values, then fail on the remaining 8 reads.

Comment: Note: +1 Great you are doing testing the result of `fscanf(fp, "%d", &a)`.  Should test `result` also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format specifier `%d` does not specify a length, so `fscanf` will read as many digits as it can; this is why you get 110 instead of just 1.

If you specify a length, like `%1d`, it will only read as many digits as you tell it to:

```
for(i = 0; i <n;++i) {
   int result=fscanf(fp, "%1d", &N[i] );  
}
```

Comment: For some reason, it works when I print N[0], N[1] and N[2] but when I try to print N[3] the output is 596567954789654

Comment: What do you have in `test.txt`? It sounds like there's something non-numeric after `110` and before `220`.

Comment: I think something's wrong with my computer or compiler???. I tried it on an online compiler and it worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

When you use fscanf with %d format parameter, it retrieves an integer type from the file. Since 110 and the others are all integers, it will directly fetch 110 from file.

So you can either use fscanf with %d parameters in a loop which iterates for a times, or if you want to get it character by character, you can use fscanf with %c parameter but it needs much more effort. So, you should use fscanf with %d parameter and fetch all digits from it by a loop for every number.

Answer (score 2):

The `fscanf(fp, "%d", &N[i] )` will catch a number and not a digit. So

```
fscanf(fp, "%d", &N[0] )  //will catch 110
fscanf(fp, "%d", &N[1] )  //will catch 220
...
```

If you want to catch digits in your array you have to use the following code:

```
for(i = 0; i <n;++i) {
    int result=fscanf(fp, "%c", &N[i] );
    if (isdigit (N[i])) N[i]-='0';
    else i--;
}
```

Comment: Actually, when I try to print N[1] 6454646712364 is the output, not 220

Comment: Really???  N[1]: 3804992
Process returned 14 (0xE)   execution time : 0.006 s
Press any key to continue.  I have no idea whats going on

Comment: @user3075022 try to compile your code with this online compiler: http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php

Comment: It worked.. what the hell is wrong with my computer? Haha, anyway I'll try to see if what you posted helps me

Comment: `fscanf(fp, "%c"` has a problem in that it first reads the left-over `\n` from the `fscanf(fp, "%d", &a)`.  Better to use `fscanf(fp, " %c"` (added space) to consume leading whitespace.